# Bundler can't resolve the correct (dependent) version of a gem that's manually installed and removed

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I have absolutely never written any Ruby programs. I'm just setting up my static blog using Jekyll.

I installed everything from Gemfile by `bundle install`. My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "github-pages"

group :jekyll-plugins do
    gem "octopress-minify-html"
end
```

One of the dependencies of the octopress plugin is uglifier 2.7.2, and it was installed correctly in the first `bundle install` call.

When trying out another plugin that depends on another version of uglifier later, I installed uglifier via

```
gem install uglifier
```

Prior to this, the only package I installed with `gem` is Bundler, and everything else is done via `bundle install`. The above command installed uglifier 4.1.9, which later caused some problems when building with Jekyll.

But then it seems I can't revert uglifier to 2.7.2. Bundler has been resolving the depencency of octopress plugin to uglifier 4.1.9 (incompatible) ever since. I tried `sudo bundle clean --force` and `sudo gem uninstall --all`, delete `~/.bundle` and `~/.gem` and start all over again, but still Bundler installs uglifier 4.1.9 as the depencency.

I tried the whole procedure on a new VM and start from `apt install ruby ruby-dev`, this time Bundler resolves the dependency to 2.7.2 correctly and I was able to build my site. It also does the resolution correctly on Travis CI.

**Question**: How can I make Bundler forget about uglifier 4.1.9 and stop the bad dependency resolution on my machine?

Note: The working directory is kept clean by deleting the whole WD and re-cloning from GitHub, so it's consistent across environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **one** of the following:

1. Run `jekyll` commands in the context of the `Gemfile`:

   ```
   bundle exec jekyll build
   ```
2. Re-align your lockfile and then *build*:

   i. Run `bundle update`

   ii. Run `bundle exec jekyll build`
3. Re-generate your lockfile and then *build*:

   i. Delete `Gemfile.lock`

   ii. Run `bundle exec jekyll build`

Comment: I already tried 1 and 3 (I should've stated this), but 2 seems new to me and I'll try it later.